# name 'latest_change_date' is not defined, how to order by datetime

Tags: python, django

in my models py I have:

```
class Profile_image(models.Model):
    latest_change_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Anon(models.Model):
    profileImages = models.ManyToManyField(Profile_image, default=None)
```

in my views py I have

```
images = loggedinanon.profileImages.order_by(latest_change_date)
```

How do I order the images in a predictable way? Can I use an integer field instead?

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, always share the **entire** error message. Do you have a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
images=loggedinanon.profileImages.order_by('latest_change_date')
```